# AVCaptureAudioDataOutput to ExtAudioFile

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c

I want to record a movie with AVCaptureSession and I also want to process the audio part. (convert to AAC and save it). I read [this sample from apple](https://developer.apple.com/library/IOs/samplecode/AVCaptureToAudioUnit/Introduction/Intro.html) but I didn't manage to make it works for my purpose and I don't think I need Audio Units. Here is my code :

```
- (void) encodeSample:(CMSampleBufferRef) sample;
{
    int nFrame = CMSampleBufferGetNumSamples(sample);
    currentSampleTime += (double) nFrame;
    AudioTimeStamp ts;
    memset(&ts, 0, sizeof(AudioTimeStamp));
    ts.mSampleTime = currentSampleTime;
    ts.mFlags |= kAudioTimeStampSampleTimeValid;

    AudioBufferList lBuffer;
    lBuffer.mNumberBuffers = 1;
    lBuffer.mBuffers[0].mNumberChannels = 2;
    lBuffer.mBuffers[0].mData = malloc(nFrame * sizeof(SInt16) * 2);
    lBuffer.mBuffers[0].mDataByteSize = nFrame * sizeof(SInt16) * 2;

    size_t bufferListSizeNeededOut;
    CMBlockBufferRef blockBufferOut = nil;
    OSStatus err = CMSampleBufferGetAudioBufferListWithRetainedBlockBuffer(sample,
                                                                  &bufferListSizeNeededOut,
                                                                  &lBuffer,
                                                                  sizeof(lBuffer),
                                                                  kCFAllocatorSystemDefault,
                                                                  kCFAllocatorSystemDefault,
                                                                  kCMSampleBufferFlag_AudioBufferList_Assure16ByteAlignment,
                                                                  &blockBufferOut);

    NSLog(@"lbuff : %ld",err);
    @synchronized(self){
        if(adtsFile)
        {
            err = ExtAudioFileWriteAsync(adtsFile, nFrame, &lBuffer);
            NSLog(@"async : %ld",err);
        }
    }
}
```

However I get a EXC_BAD_ACCESS after 3 calls :

```
2013-09-04 15:01:35.669 Recoder[13683:1803] lbuff : 0
2013-09-04 15:01:35.673 Recoder[13683:1803] async : 0
2013-09-04 15:01:37.194 Recoder[13683:5b03] lbuff : 0
2013-09-04 15:01:37.197 Recoder[13683:5b03] async : 0
2013-09-04 15:01:37.201 Recoder[13683:5b03] lbuff : 0
// bad access here
```

I can also share the code I use to init my ExtAudioFile but I believe it works well (i use it in another app I made)

Comment: Although I can't answer your question, a good resource I found for my purposes (converting iPod music to raw PCM data) came from [Chris Adamson's blog.](http://www.subfurther.com/blog/2010/07/19/from-iphone-media-library-to-pcm-samples-in-dozens-of-confounding-potentially-lossy-steps/) Hope it may lead you closer to your answer.